# React State is not in sync

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call the function getSearch result to implement the autocomplete functionality for search.
React state is not in sync hence, function is called with lag of one character. Request suggestion to solve the issue.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  SearchBar,
  IconContainer
} from '../../styles/componentStyles/SearchBox/SearchBox';
import SearchIcon from './SearchIcon';
import SearchResult from './SearchResult';

import GenreFancyItemContext from '../../Context/genreFancyITem/GenreFancyItemContext';

export default function SearchBox() {
  const genreFancyItemContext = useContext(GenreFancyItemContext);

  const { getSearchResults, searchResults } = genreFancyItemContext;

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  const onChange = e => {
    console.log('On change executes');
    var text = e.target.value;
    setSearchText(text);
    getSearchResults(searchText);
    console.log(searchResults);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchBar
        type="text"
        name="searchSting"
        placeholder="  Search Fancyitem..."
        onChange={onChange}
        value={searchText}
      />
      <SearchResult />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to `setSearchText` to make sure that the previous changes are done before making a change.

```
setSearchText(text);
```

can be

```
setSearchText((prevText) => {
  return text;
});
```

but there's a better way of doing what you're trying to do using the `useEffect` hook.

```
export default function SearchBox() {
  const genreFancyItemContext = useContext(GenreFancyItemContext);

  const { getSearchResults, searchResults } = genreFancyItemContext;

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
   getSearchResults(searchText);
  },[searchText])

  const onChange = e => {
    console.log('On change executes');
    var text = e.target.value;
    setSearchText(text);
    // getSearchResults(searchText);
    console.log(searchResults);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchBar
        type="text"
        name="searchSting"
        placeholder="  Search Fancyitem..."
        onChange={onChange}
        value={searchText}
      />
      <SearchResult />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: @SagarMahadik There's a better and awesome way to do that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here was your issue:

```
getSearchResults(searchText)
```

`searchText` here is actually previous state.

`getSearchResults(text);` would also solve the problem. However, solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954557/4012133) more readable. I am voting for it :)